# If class found condition

Tags: jquery

I need to check if an input field has no value then I'll append a notice. However if such notice has been already appended but another script I not need to do anything.

The only difference between my notice and a notice that could be added by another script is that my will have an extra class in it.

```
// notice set by script
<div class="noticeMessage"></div>

// my Notice format
<div class="noticeMessage myNotice"></div>
```

So, how do I check is other notice has been set and it's not mine?

```
if ($('#myField').val() == '' && $('.noticeMessage').length == 0) {
   // add my notice      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use hasClass()

```
if ( $('element').hasClass('className') ) {
    //do something
}
```

Well if you want the opposite then you just use !

```
if ( !($('element').hasClass('className')) ) {
    //do something if class does not exist
}
```

By the way $(this).val() returns false if it is empty

Comment: Sorry, I did not do a good job explaining... I can only add message if there are no values AND there is no notice present THAT HAS NO .myNotice in it.

Comment: The value part I think you got already so I won't put it in my answer. If you still can't implement this then comment again

Answer (score 0):

Try using below to check if your `.myNotice` is present along with the `noticeMessage`..

```
$('.noticeMessage.myNotice').length
```

but I am not sure why you can't just use `$('.myNotice').length`